# javafx-2, ListView selectedIndices property of selectionModel inconsistent when items removed

Tags: java, listview, javafx-2

In a javafx-2 ListView, i noticed a strange (yet workaround-able) behavior in getSelectedIndices. 
getSelectedIndices property (of SelectionModel) is an observable list that should ever contain the selected item or the selected items if multiple selection is allowed.
But if i add an item, select it and then remove it, you may expect that the selection would contain no items, but actually it does contain an item and precisely -1.
Here is the siplest code that shows this fact.

```
public class T01 extends Application {

public static void main (String [] args) { launch(args);}

ListView<String> listView;

//just create the controls, that is a BorderPane with a ListView in its center
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

    listView = new ListView();

    borderPane.setCenter(listView);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));

    primaryStage.show();

    doTest();

}

//doTest: add an item, select it, remove it and inspect the selection model again
public void doTest() {

    System.out.println("A) before adding items");
    printSelectedItem(listView);

    listView.getItems().add("first");

    listView.getSelectionModel().select(0);

    System.out.println("B) added an item and selected");
    printSelectedItem(listView);


    listView.getItems().remove(0);

    System.out.println("C) removed the item");
    printSelectedItem(listView);

}

public void printSelectedItem(ListView listView) {
    ObservableList<Integer> list = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
    System.out.println("The selectedIndices property contains: " + list.size() + " element(s):");
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) { System.out.println(i + ")" + list.get(i)); }
}

}
```

and here is my output:

```
run:
A) before adding items
The selectedIndices property contains: 0 element(s):
B) added an item and selected
The selectedIndices property contains: 1 element(s):
0)0
C) removed the item
The selectedIndices property contains: 1 element(s):
0)-1
```

The case "C" shows the "unexpected" behavior. Maybe documented somewhere?

Environement information:
javafx.runtime.version: 2.2.3-b05
java.runtime.version: 1.6.0_29-b11
os.name: Windows 7
os.version: 6.1

Comment: See the api doc of `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty()`

Comment: This question is not about selectedIndexProperty, that is a single int. It is about selectedIndicesProperty that is an ObservableList